# How can i convert days of week selected into , separated integers in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the checkboxes of week days and user select them

The JS object is like this

`{"mon":true,"tue":true,"wed":true,"thu":false,"fri":false,"sat":false,"sun":false}`

Now i want to convert it into string of , separated value like.

`0,1,2` to store in database where monday is 0 and so on. so if only sunday is selected then it will be

`7` only

I have tried this

```
 var b = days;
 days = days.map(function (a) {
  return b.indexOf(a);
            });
```

Comment: Just to clarify:  If Monday is 0, wouldn't Sunday be 6 instead of 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this which uses a lookup table to convert days of the week to day numbers, accumulates the selected numbers in an array and then turns the array into a comma separated string.

```
function getDayList(data) {
    var dayNumMap = {"mon":1,"tue":2,"wed":3,"thu":4,"fri":5,"sat":6,"sun":7};
    var list = [], item;
    // iterate all days pass in
    for (var day in data) {
        // if the checkbox was selected
        if (data[day]) {
            item = dayNumMap[day];
            // if it's valid data
            if (item) {
                // add the day number to the list
                list.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
    // return a comma separated string
    return list.sort().join(",");
}

// data from checkboxes
var formData = {"mon":true,"tue":true,"wed":true,"thu":false,"fri":false,"sat":false,"sun":false};

var str = getDayList(formData);
```

Comment: But i get that JS object from my checkboxes array, so true false means that checkbox is checked or not. i can do {"1": 1} but that will change my labels of checkboxes

Comment: @KKJOJ - Hmmm, that was not clear at all from your question.  Geez, guess I have to rewrite my answer.

Comment: @KKJOJ - OK, rewrote my answer based on your new description.

Comment: Thanks for that. That looks very big. Is it possible to reduce in few lines if possible

Comment: Since object keys aren't guaranteed to be ordered, could this return `2,3,1` instead of `1,2,3`?  If so, perhaps changing `dayNumMap` to an array and iterating through it would be beneficial.

Comment: @RickHitchcock - if the desire is sorted, then just change `list.join(",")` to `list.sort().join(",")`.  I wouldn't consider searching through an array to be an ideal implementation when a simple lookup table can be used.

Comment: @KKJOJ - It's correct, it checks the input data for correctness, it works, it's commented and it's in function form.  And, now you want to remove a few lines?  Why?  There is no goal in programming to accomplish a task in the fewest lines of code.  Correct, clear, robust, documented, reusable, maintainable and appropriate performance ALL come before fewest lines of code in the programming hierarchy.  Plus your question didn't say anything about fewest lines of code.  If it did, I wouldn't have responded because that is rarely a real-world important goal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = {
  "mon": true,
  "tue": true,
  "wed": true,
  "thu": false,
  "fri": false,
  "sat": true,
  "sun": false
};

var sel = [], i = 0;
$.each(json, function(a, b) {
  if (b)
    sel.push(i);//<-- selected index
  i++;
});

$('#out').text('selected: ' + sel.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="out">please wait ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, which should work if some of the object's properties are missing or out of order:

```js
var obj = {"mon":true,"tue":true,"wed":true,"thu":false,"fri":false,"sat":false,"sun":false}

var s= '';
for(var i in obj) {
  if(obj[i]) {
    s+= 'montuewedthufrisatsun'.indexOf(i)/3;
  }
}
s= s.split('').sort().join(',')
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are implicitely assuming that your object property order will remain same while iterating and thus you can easily map your property name to index. e.g "mon" mapped to 0. But this is not a guaranteed cross browser scenario.

> The [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order.

Therefore to have a more robust and predictable approach you should add the mapping value to object itself

```
var days = {"mon":{index:0,value:true},"tue":{index:1,value:true}};
var val = getConcatanatedDays(days);
function getConcatanatedDays(obj) {
    var val = [];
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop].value) {
            val.push(obj[prop].index);
        }
    }
    return val.join(',');
}
```

You may also consider to store the days in array so that you dont have to store the day val separately and you will get the flexibility of looping through array.

```
var days = [{"mon":true},{}];//ordered iteration
```